# How do you properly rotate an overlay on the map?

Tags: ios, rotation, mapkit, overlay

I've created a custom overlay that contains a geometric shape for an iOS app.  I would like to rotate it around it's center (or rather the center of the boundingMapRect).  From what I understand, using CGContextRotateCTM(contextRef, angle) rotates the overlay using the upper left corner of the boundingMapRect as the origin, so if I rotate my overlay a small amount clockwise it appears down and to the left of it's previous location.

I thought that if I could capture the initial center of the overlay's bounding rectangle, then the center after the rotation then I could calculate the coordinate difference and reposition the overlay using CGContextTranslateCTM.  My problem with that is that the center locations were the same before and after the CGContextRotateCTM call.  Is there some way to force that call into effect so I can get the new center location?  Is there a better way to do this?

I saw some references to using half the width and height of the overlay to reposition, but I don't understand how that helps as it is constant.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution, run on swift 3:

Assume `centerPoint` is a `CGPoint` that you want to rotate around.

```
let a = sqrt(pow(centerPoint.x, 2.0) + pow(centerPoint.y, 2.0))

let sub1 = (centerPoint.y / a) * cos(angle / 2.0)
let sub2 = (centerPoint.x / a) * sin(angle / 2.0)
let deltaX = -2 * a * sin((0 - angle) / 2.0) * (sub1 + sub2)

let sub3 = (centerPoint.x / a) * cos(angle / 2.0)
let sub4 = (centerPoint.y / a) * sin(angle / 2.0)
let deltaY = 2 * a * sin((0 - angle) / 2.0) * (sub3 - sub4)

context.translateBy(x: deltaX, y: deltaY)

context.rotate(by: angle)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting an anchor point for the rotation? After setting the anchorpoint the rotation will be around the center of the view.

Somehting like:

```
[yourView.layer setAnchorPoint:CGPointMake( 0.5, 0.5 )]; // center of the view
```

See the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Articles/Layers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006082) for more details.

Comment: How do you rotate it afterwards? And your link to Apple docs doesn't exist.