# Adjust Frame of Overlay without affecting MKMapView beneath it?

Tags: ios, mkmapview, overlay, cgrect

I've got an `MKMapView` and overlay (a curved line) on top of it.  I'd like to be able to adjust the overlay's frame to move it across the map and transform its height/width (and thus distort the image) as necessary from user inputs.  But here's the trick: I DON'T want to move the map itself, just the shape overlaid on top of it.

I've contemplated just erasing and re-applying the overlay, but the input changes so frequently (it's based on the user's compass direction which is constantly changing ever-so-slightly) that the shape just ends up flickering off and on in a very distracting way.  So I feel like I need to adjust the shape as-is, rather than removing it, if I can.

Thing is, when I try to access the overlay to try to transform it, XCode tells me that the `self.mapView.overlays` array is read-only.  I've [found questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5994789/how-do-you-properly-rotate-an-overlay-on-the-map) on Stack Overflow, though, that seem to imply that overlays can be rotated, and thus edited.

Does anyone know how to pull this off?  I would provide code, but aside from the simple "add overlay" function in `viewDidLoad`, I don't have any yet...

Comment: I can imagine the overlays array being read only, but the objects in it shouldn't be. Get or keep a handle to the overlay and start making changes to it, so long as the object stays in the overlays array the map will keep drawing it.

Answer (score 0):

When you add an overlay, why don't you keep an external reference to it? Then you can use this property to change its frame (like you saw on the attached questions) without removing and adding que overlay.